# Responsive Grid JQuery issue on CodePen

Tags: jquery, grid

I'm trying to get this responsive grid to work on CodePen. For some reason it is not lining up correctly when the page loads. It does resize correctly when I resize my browser. How can I get it to work when the page loads?

http://codepen.io/KoniG87/pen/vyqds (The original author says that it only doesn't work when using percentage widths, but I tried pixel widths and that didn't work either.)

Here is the CSS in question:

```
    #big_box{
max-width:100%;
background:#fff;
margin:0 auto; 
height:auto;    
}
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).resize(function() {
            var winWidth = $(window).width();
            var parentWidth = $('#big_box').innerWidth();
             var divider = parentWidth /96 ; 

                $('#big_box img').css( "margin", divider );

            if(winWidth < 321) {
            parentWidth = 320;
           $('#big_box').innerWidth('100%');
            $('.box-1').width( divider * 94) ;        //1 column
            $('.box-2').width( divider * 94) ;
            $('.box-3').width( divider * 94) ;
            $('.box-4').width( divider * 94) ;
            } 
                else if(winWidth < 480) {
            parentWidth = 480;
                  $('#big_box').innerWidth('100%');
            $('.box-1').width(divider * 46).height(divider * 46) ;    //2 col
            $('.box-2').width(divider * 94).height(divider * 46) ;
            $('.box-3').width(divider * 46).height(divider * 94) ;
            $('.box-3').css( "float","left" ) ;
            $('.box-4').width(divider * 94).height(divider * 94) ;
            } 
                else if(winWidth < 768) {
            parentWidth = 768;
                   $('#big_box').innerWidth(480);
            $('.box-1').width(divider * 30).height(divider * 30) ;    //3 col
            $('.box-2').width(divider * 62).height(divider * 30);
            $('.box-3').width(divider * 30).height(divider * 62);
            $('.box-3:first').css( "float","right" ) ;
            $('.box-4').width(divider * 62).height(divider * 62) ;
            } 
                else if(winWidth < 1024) {
            parentWidth = 1024;
                  $('#big_box').innerWidth(720);
            $('.box-1').width(divider * 22).height(divider * 22) ;    //4 col
            $('.box-2').width(divider * 46).height(divider * 22) ;
            $('.box-3').width(divider * 46).height(divider * 94) ;
            $('.box-3').css( "float","right" ) ;
            $('.box-4').width(divider * 46).height(divider * 46) ;

            }
                else if(winWidth < 1224) {
            parentWidth = 1224;
                  $('#big_box').innerWidth(960);
            $('.box-1').width(divider * 14).height(divider * 14);    //6 col
            $('.box-2').width(divider * 30).height(divider * 14) ;
            $('.box-2:first').width(divider * 62).height(divider * 30) ;
            $('#big_box img:nth-child(12)').width(divider * 62).height(divider * 30) ;
            $('#big_box img:nth-child(23)').width(divider * 62).height(divider * 30) ;
            $('.box-3').width(divider * 14).height(divider * 30) ;
            $('.box-3').css( "float","left" ) ;
            $('.box-4').width(divider * 30).height(divider * 30) ;
            }
                else {
            parentWidth = 1824;

            };
        });
$(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I've never thought of trying to trigger resize without actually resizing the window.  I would suggest this approach instead:

```
function stuffToDo(){
   //do all the things
}

$(document).ready(stuffToDo);
$(window).resize(stuffToDo);
```

Just remember the resize is going to fire a ton so you might want to think about adding a debounce function ([from David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)).

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Comment: Hi fauxserious, this seems like a great logical example, but I'm not quite good enough yet at JavaScript to know how to apply this code to the code I already posted. I tried adding it word for word above what I had, and that didn't work. I'm pretty sure I need to customize it, and I'm not sure how to do that. I also tried replacing the original function and $(document) and $(window) functions with yours, and that didn't work either. I practice JavaScript sometimes with codecombat.com, but I'm not fully proficient in it.

Comment: Well, "do all the things" is where you'd put all the logic for the function.  In your code that would be starting with `var winWidth = $(window).width();` and ending in `else {parentWidth = 1824;};` Then you trigger that function (stuffToDo) on both when the document is ready (fully loaded) and when the window is resized.  Don't worry about the debounce function if you're new, just focus on getting the effect first.

Comment: I put my code inside the function stuffToDo(){ brackets } and put the document ready and window resize functions at the end. I'm wondering if it caused a feedback loop because the page won't stop loading.